# Why can't I print the integers of an array with using the " * "?

Tags: c++

When I create an `array` and a pointer to that `array`, why cant I print out the numbers by writing `*p[3]` instead of just `p[3]`. When I am doing it with normal numbers like the variable `b` in the example, I can only access the pointers value by typing the `*` operator before `e` (i.e `*e`). And why isn't it `int *p = &array` instead of `int *p = array`?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int array[5] = {3, 3, 4, 6, 7};
    int *p = array;
    std::cout << p << "\n" << p[3];

    int b = 5;
    int *e = &b;
    std::cout << "\n" << e << " " << *e;
}
```

Comment: Since `p[3]` already is an `int` what do you expect to achieve by adding a `*` before that?

Comment: `p[3]` is equivalent to `*(p + 3)`. That's by definition, so you can't add another `*` yourself.

Comment: `*e` means exactly the same thing as `e[0]`.

Comment: `p` is not a pointer to the array, it is a pointer to the first element of the array – `int *p = array;` is equivalent to `int *p = &array[0];`. A pointer to the array would be `int (*p)[5] = &array;`.

Comment: do not spam tags. How it is related to the C language?

Comment: Detail: "and a pointer to that array" --> With `int *p = array;`, `p` is a pointer to the first element of `array`, an `int *`, _not_ the array.  To point to an _array_ use `auto p = &a;rray` or the like.

Answer (score 3):

> why cant I print out the numbers by writing `*p[3]` instead of just `p[3]`

The expression `p[3]` is, by definition of the subscript operator `[]`, equivalent to `*(p+3)`, which means that the `int` element that exists 3 elements after the element pointed to by `p` is retrieved.

Therefore, `*p[3]` is equivalent to `**(p+3)`, which does not make sense, because `*(p+3)` is an object of type `int`, which cannot be dereferenced. Only pointers can be dereferenced.

> And why isn't it `int *p = &array` instead of `int *p = array`?

In the declaration `int *p = array;`, the expression `array` will [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/12149471) to a pointer to the first element of the array, i.e. to `&array[0]`. Therefore, `p` will point to the first element of the array.

However, if you write `int *p = &array;` instead, then `array` will not decay to `&array[0]`. Instead, the expression `&array` will evaluate to a pointer to the entire array, not to a pointer to the first element of the array. This means that the type of the pointer is not `int *` (pointer to a single `int`), but rather `int (*)[5]` (pointer to an array of 5 `int` elements). A pointer of type `int (*)[5]` cannot be assigned to a pointer of type `int *` without an explicit cast. For this reason, the line `int *p = &array;` is not valid.

Comment: Removed my answer as your explanation covers every aspect much deeper. Well said.

Comment: The classic mind-bender is `3[p]` has the same effect also being equivalent to `*(3+p)` and pointer/integer arithmetic being commutative.

Answer (score 0):

`operator[]` dereferences the pointer. You can also get a pointed to value by writing `e[0]`. Using both `operator[]` and the dereferencing asterisk would dereference twice.